# A real limit with a sum

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a>0$, consider the real sequence $\left( A_{n}\right) _{n>1}$ where $%
A_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-k/n)^{an}$ for each $n>1$. Prove or disprove that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }A_{n}=\frac{1}{e^{a}-1}\text{.}
$$

Thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem applied to the counting measure space gives you what you need (the monotonicity of the sequence converging to $e$ has been covered on this site before, if you want to check that out)

Comment: But in general? Please, please, don't dump problem statements as commands! This site encourages *you* to show your own working, thoughts and context for *your* question, so that you can be constructively helped

Comment: Hint: $(1-k/n)\leq e^{-k/n}$.